# In Kotlin, Is there way to define generic arguments which can only be certain types when they don't extend a common base class (String/ByteArray)?

Tags: kotlin, generics, overloading, kotlin-sealed

I have 2 similar functions:

```
fun f1(String key, value: JsonNullable<ByteArray?>): Modification? {
    return if (value.isPresent) {
        when (val rawValue = value.get()) {
            null -> delete(key)
            else -> bar(field, rawValue)
        }
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

==============

```
fun f2(String key, value: JsonNullable<String?>): Modification? {
    return if (value.isPresent) {
        when (val rawValue = value.get()) {
            null -> delete(key)
            else -> bar(field, rawValue)
        }
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

Is there way to replace it with the single function using generic ?

bar function is overloaded:

```
fun bar(field: String, value: JsonNullable<ByteArray?>)...
fun bar(field: String, value: JsonNullable<String?>)...
```

Comment: I recommend reading [the documentation about generic functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#generic-functions). I found this by googling "kotlin generics".

Comment: Well. My question is about upper bound. I see example with AND(using where keyword) but I need OR. Looks like it is impossible. Isn't it ?

Comment: What is the signature of your `delete` function, or is it overloaded too?

Comment: Yes, it's impossible.

Comment: @gstackoverflow What do you mean by "AND" and "OR"? Where is there any boolean logic in your code?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I mean that argument could either `JsonNullable<String?>` or `JsonNullable<ByteArray?>`

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yup, that's how generics work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking about this incorrectly String does not inherit from ByteArray (or vice versa) and they don't inherit from any base class except Object.

> Upper bounds
> The most common type of constraint is an upper bound, which corresponds to Java's extends keyword:

So unless you just want it to be anything that extends Object (Both String an ByteArray do extend object) you will need to use generics.

I think this example will give you a basic understanding

https://pl.kotl.in/umls8tYpV

You use a generic and then use an if or switch statement to do something that is specific per type.

In the case of using an upper bounds with Object it would be [these](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html)

So if this doesn't answer your question you should probably reword it to make it a little more precise about what you are looking for.

*Fair Warning... Java/Scala Developer do very little Kotlin so some stuff may be overly verbose*

Also if you want to ONLY accept ByteArray or String you can do this...

```kotlin
sealed class JsonType {
    data class JsonString(val value: String) : JsonType()
    data class JsonByteArray(val value: ByteArray) : JsonType()
}

data class JsonNullable<T>(val value: T?)

fun f2(key: String, value: JsonNullable<JsonType>?): String? {
    when (val jsonType = value?.value) {
        is JsonType.JsonString -> {
            println("Welp it is String: ${jsonType.value}")
        }
        is JsonType.JsonByteArray -> {
            println("Welp it is Byte: ${String(jsonType.value)}")
        }
        null -> {
            println("JSON is null")
        }
        else -> {
            println("Unknown JSON type")
        }
    }
    return null
}

/**
 * You can edit, run, and share this code.
 * play.kotlinlang.org
 */
fun main() {
    f2("null", null)
    f2("String", JsonNullable(JsonType.JsonString("String Value")))
    f2("Byte", JsonNullable(JsonType.JsonByteArray("Byte Value".toByteArray())))
    f2("Null JSON", JsonNullable(null))
}
```

Comment: Also you could have gotten all this from ChatGPT (I used it to make it less verbose since I am used to Java) so I would start relying on that a bit more.

Comment: so I have to chage declaration of bar.  Is it correct ?

Comment: Not sure I follow I would extend my web example to do what you want for debugging

Comment: I would use chatgpt again https://postimg.cc/qzYpXvLR

Comment: You dont have to change bar if you still want 2 seperate methods but if you want to use generics you would. Again I suggest asking chatgpt

Comment: Should be a sealed interface instead of class in this case. By the way, this answer breaks the no AI rule. https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: Thanks ten four I will read over that didnt know

Comment: @Jackie my post contains bar method declaration. If you apply your solution using bar - you will see compile error

Comment: Not sure what you mean you should be able to construct an example with the online compiler I used if you want to be more specific

Comment: In your example you create your custom data classes JsonString and JsonByteArray. What if I want to use existingClasses ?

Answer (score 0):

Following [the Kotlin documentation on generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#generic-functions), you can write a single generic function using a type variable:

```
fun <T> f(String key, value: JsonNullable<T>): Modification? {
    return if (value.isPresent) {
        when (val rawValue = value.get()) {
            null -> delete(key)
            else -> bar(field, rawValue)
        }
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you noticed the declaration of bar function ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow No, I didn't. Did you try my solution? What happens?

Comment: compile error because bar declaration is
`fun bar(field: String, value: JsonNullable<ByteArray?>)...
fun bar(field: String, value: JsonNullable<String?>)...
`

Comment: @gstackoverflow Can you also make `bar()` generic? Or better yet, the class that contains `f1()`, `f2()` and `bar()`?

Comment: unfortunately I can't change bar. It is existing java(!) method from the library

Comment: It will help if you show that actual function call instead of a generalized `bar()` then.